# Swift Subclassing Subclasses of UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've created the sample *Master-Detail Application* in Xcode and I'm trying to setup a child view controller of the `MasterViewController` (say `UltimateViewController`) using:

```
class UltimateViewController: MasterViewController {}
```

This compiles, but if I open the storyboard I am unable to change (with autocomplete) the class name for the view controller to `UltimateViewController`. If I enter the name manually I am unable to wire up any   existing `@IBOutlets` or `@IBActions`. Any pre-existing outlets show the warning indicator and the application crashes on launch. How can I do this type of inheritance?

Comment: Iam able to do this. What error you are getting? May be quitting and relaunching of Xcode will fix this

Comment: @Anil I'm getting a `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key mainCollectionView` (one of my IBOutlets).

Comment: How do you declare your `mainCollectionView`?

Comment: ... Or maybe it's an old, wild outlet, which somehow hasn't been deleted and still exists in the IB file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

StoryBoard sometimes does not re-index project files when you create new ones so they are not available to choose when you want to change the subclass in storyboard. For me I usually Clean the project, Close Xcode, launch XCode, build and the class is now available.

You can also try deleting derived data for the project so it will for a total re-index of the project files. Lastly verify that the target of the file is correct.

Lastly make sure youre using xcode 6 :)